# Resolving HLF official docker image vulnerabilities

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, ubuntu-20.04, production, docker-image

I have a **HLF(2.2.3)** network setup in a private cloud platform(**ubuntu20.04 LTS**).

Docker images are pulled from **dockerHub** to cloud VMs local using below command,

> curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 2.2.3 1.5.0
> (shortened url bit.ly/2ysbOFE)

When I scan the pulled images using "**Trivy**" tool (installed cloud-local) I found tons of vulnerabilities.

How am I suppose to fix these vulnerabilities? I'm aware of shelling out money, buying license and getting frequent patches, I don't want to choose that solution.

Looking for a methods that can be executed to resolve this vulnerabilities within the cloud VMs.

Tried to pull latest images and ran scan on the same, even those images have vulnerabilities.

Please suggest.

1. How to resolve this vulnerabilities?
2. How are these problems handled in real-time projects? (I'm new to prod deployment and any insights on this are welcome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on dockerhub, the published hyperledger fabric images are for development and testing only, not for production. If you want that level of support then you either have to buy images from a provider (but as you stated you don't want to do that) or you build and maintain your own images and do the work yourself. This is what any production deployment should be doing.

One important point to note: Just because a scanner reports a vulnerability doesn't mean you are actually vulnerable. Most scanners only look at what you have not what you are using so you should make a risk assessment of each of the reported vulnerabilities to determine if you are indeed susceptible.

Comment: thanks for the answer. 
"you build and maintain your own images"
can you please provide more details, examples or study materials on this?
because I was unable to get any HLF service's DockerFile. how would I build own images?

Comment: I don't have any real world examples I can show you, sorry. But what I would expect people to do would be to either take the officially released binaries and copy that into some base linux image they maintain or for more control to take the actual source of a specically tagged version of hyperledger fabric and build the binary usually as part of a multistage docker build to create an image

Comment: you can see how hyperledger fabric defines their docker builds here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/main/images

Comment: thanks a lot. that should be a good starter. cheers

Comment: Fabric 2.5 may change how these images are built hopefully for the better, should be released early next year

Comment: I overlooked this vulnerability issue and have the entire setup ready using 2.2.3. now this has become a show stopper. I'm not gonna have a great holiday season.

Comment: You should be able to move to the latest 2.2 fabric release without issue, the fabric binaries themselves should not have any known security issues. If there are then fabric will address them. If there a security issues within the base image that you have chosen then again it's a risk assessment. Just because it's reported doesn't mean you are vulnerable you need to assess each reported vulnerability to decide if it affects you or not.